# Rename a tile in the Start screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

How can I rename a tile on the Start screen?

[image]

For example, how can I change "eclipse" to "Eclipse Juno"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.itworld.com/windows/308063/rename-tiles-windows-8), also shown in this [ClipTraining video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fNBKwOx39U)

1. **Right click** on the tile you want to rename.
2. Left click on "**open file location**"
3. The **file's shortcut** will appear in Windows Explorer.
4. Click on the text to change the name, or **right-click** it and click "**rename**."
5. The new name will apply to the tile as well as the file.

Comment: I renamed the file, but the tile is not updated. Is there a way to refresh the start screen?

Comment: the video seems to show that just pressing windows key should suffice

Comment: @Chin It is instant

Comment: Some apps/icons don't have option "open file location". How can I rename those apps?